# .htaccess display_startup_errors setting depends on php script config file

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I am creating my own framework as a learning process. There is a config file, where people can set whether the framework is in development mode or not.

```
<?PHP
$project[security][dev_mode] = true;
?>
```

Display_startup_errors is defined in .htaccess, to indicate if syntax errors should be shown. I would prefer if users don't need to mess with the .htaccess file, so that it 'adjusts' to the settings in the config file. Anyone got an idea *if* and *how* it is possible to somehow let .htaccess check the contents of the php file and act accordingly?

A solution which sets the display_startup_errors in an other way than .htaccess is welcome too ;-).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `display_startup_errors` is going to be something people will want to set themselves. I wouldn't want a php framework to try and take control of the http server. Having said that, I don't know that theres an easy way to accomplish what you're talking about. htaccess is just a file of directives iirc.

Comment: You're probably right, but this framework won't be distributed on a large scale ;-). Thanks.

Comment: Why use .htaccess to display error instead of ini_se() configuration of php?

Comment: @kaii What I understood is that syntax errors cannot be set using ini_set()... Otherwise, is there somehow a possibility to overrule the display_startup_errors setting set using .htaccess in the php script?

Comment: @dirk It is possible to diplay syntax error using php.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$iDevMode = ( $project['security']['dev_mode'] ) ? 1 : 0;

ini_set('display_errors', $iDevMode);
?>
```

To toggle based on the definition. This is an ugly ternary operation (that you could convert to an **if** statement for practice) and will need to be processed very early in your program.

Also note that PHP will throw a notice for not encapsulating your associative array references in quotes, as I have above.

Comment: As the script terminates as soon as it notices the syntax error (before processing any code), I understood that display_startup_errors cannot be set using ini_set...

Answer (score 1):

An alternatives for the use of .htaccess in handling error is  creating a configurable
php file that can be set upon the stages of development,production and testing just like other frameworks does.

```
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Or manually try to use ini_set() to properly set the configuration for error handling to on

```
// change settings for error handler to show errors
// $this setup is used for checking errors for development to be shown.... 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```